# File API, Persistent link to a local file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on some web script based on a game (to port a game to the web).
The scripts download data from my web host so the loading is slow (have to download each files : maps, models, textures, ...).
To correct this, I added an option that allow users to select their local game data in their computer (using the File API - drag and drop) to parse content directly from local and avoid downloading multiple megas from the web, the result is incredibly fast.

Here the problem : each time they reload the browser, they have to re-select their files, again and again. It's not user-friendly.

So, is there a way to keep a reference from this game archive to avoid the user to re-do the drag and drop each time ? I know about security concern, just want to know if there is something like a persistent URL.createObjectURL().

**Note:** the game data is about ~2Go, so it's not possible to store it in the FileSystem API (and I don't want to copy it, it's waste space to copy data when you can just keep a reference to it).

Thank you :)

Comment: I would also like an answer to this...

Comment: I bet you could use a plugin like Flash.

Comment: @qxz thx but in my case flash isn't a solution

Comment: I think [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537696/remember-and-repopulate-file-input) may answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

#### You have to have an input from the user

It is not possible to access the files on a client's computer without the user confirming it. Once the user chooses a file (You can listen to it with the `change` event), you can then use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for example to read the file.

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const fs = new FileReader();
    fs.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    fs.onloadend = function() {
        document.getElementById("output").innerText = fs.result;
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

#### Using `localStorage` to store a fraction of your files

You could use the [`localStorage API`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store some of your files, but the [capacity is very limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Storage_size), especially for a project like yours (maximum of 5 to 10 MB on current most popular browsers).

This would make your coding much harder, as you would have to check every time what was stored or not, and load what is not saved.

#### Caching

By using [caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching), you basically fall into the same problem as you are with `localStorage`: each browser has its own maximum capacity.

The advantage of this method is that you do not have to worry about what has been loaded or not, as the browser will do this by itself.

#### Using Flash

Now if you really do not care at all about security, you could use a Flash plugin to store and load the files, and then use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to load the data in your JavaScript code.

```
ExternalInterface.call("loaded", filename, data);

// And then in JavaScript:
// function loaded(filename, data)
// ...
```

You could use [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to save and load your data.

I am not an AS3 expert, please excuse any clumsiness.

#### A Desktop application?

Last option would be converting and bundling your game into a desktop application, for example by bundling it through [electron](http://electron.atom.io), and then using for example [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), which is currently the [suggested](http://electron.atom.io/community/) tool by electron for persistant storage.

Comment: Flash nor desktop application aren't viable solution for me. I've already done it using hybrid app using electron but i'd like same behaviour in a browser only app. Then the answer seems quite obvious: 'not possible...'. I guess your answer could be useful for other readers though

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using [IndexedDB](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/). It is supported in recent browsers including Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (macOS and iOS). IndexedDB allows you to save `Blob`, `File` or `ArrayBuffer` as values in an IndexedDB object store.

Check this [IndexedDB: Store file as File or Blob or ArrayBuffer. What is the best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803363/indexeddb-store-file-as-file-or-blob-or-arraybuffer-what-is-the-best-option).

Comment: I'm already using indexedDB but i'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve to duplicate file.

Comment: What are your files' keys? File names are available from the Drag & Drop API and File API. Perhaps you can index the file names and compare those file names with a list from the HTML page or an API?