# Set <input type="file"> path on a trusted machine

Tags: c#, javascript, html, input, upload

I'm trying to set the path of,

```
<input type="file">
```

with JavaScript or C# on my own machine. I know there's security preventing you from doing this, although is there anyway I can disable this feature on my machine for personal use.

Comment: No, there is not. You can work-around this by using Flash or Java-applet based file uploaders, but YMMV.

Comment: Sorry, impossible. I've looked into it and it simply cannot be done. Otherwise you could auto submit the form and upload a file without user consent, a security breach.

Comment: A full referenced explanation (by me) why this can't be done can be found in this possible duplicate: [Remember and Repopulate File Input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079)