# How do I specify the host for a websocket connection?

Tags: javascript, websocket, tornado

I have a page that open a websocket connection back to the server. The websocket server is ws://127.0.0.1:5000/ws when in development and ws://www.mymachine.com/ws when deployed to production. Is there a short hand for this, so I don't have to re-write this URI manually `from 127.0.0.1:5000` to `www.mymachine.com` when I deploy?

I've tried `ws://ws` but it doesn't work. I'm trying to get the same behavior as a normal url where you can use `/index` and it will go to 127.0.0.1:5000/index or www.mymachine.com/index depending on where it is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
I solved using:

```
 var uri= window.location.host + window.location.pathname + 'ws'
  if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
    mysocket.connect('ws://' + uri);
  } else {
    mysocket.connect('wss://' +uri);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from 1 simple variable in the top of your (initialization-)script, you could look into the [File API - A URL for Blob and File](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url) reference:

```
This specification defines a scheme with URLs of the sort:
blob:550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000#aboutABBA.
```

These are stored in an `URL store` and browsers should even have their own mini HTTP-server aboard so one can use these urls in css, img src and even XMLHttpRequest.

Your initialization-script would then use an if/else to build your url-object and put it in the store.
Some more info is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079). (Besides, backwards compatibility is kind of not your problem when using web-sockets..)

Hope this springs some idea's to your mind.