# How to pass hard coded file path to File API?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I want file name, size and type using `File API` in `javascript` but without any control means I want to pass hard coded file path. Is any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

So you *want to pass hard coded file path* using javascript.

Thank goodness, in javascript (run inside the browser) you can't do that.
Only the user can populate a `<input type="file">` element or `File` objects in a `FileList`.

> On setting, if the new value is the empty string, it must empty the list of selected files; otherwise, it must throw an InvalidStateError exception.

and

> The HTMLInputElement interface [HTML] has a readonly attribute of type FileList...

See a thorough write-up including HTML5 features here: [Remember and Repopulate File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks to all. I am getting the file name, size and type through html5  but I was looking for whether it is possible or not by hard coded path. So thank you for your reply.