# HTML "File" / OpenFile Dialog workaround

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open local mp4 movies in a webpage and play it just there.
No uploads to anywhere, nothing else.
I use my own buttons with below workaround which works with Safari 7.1.3 just fine.

```
<label for="fileToOpen">
 <button type="file"  id="loadMedia" class="loadMediabutton button">Load Movie</button>
</label>
<input type="File" name="loadMedia" id="fileToOpen" style="display:none">
```

Now my question, if someone can help to proceed:

1. How to retrieve the movie's local url from the `<input>` tag ?
2. How to pass the url to the `<video>` tag `src` attribute ?
3. How to avoid sandboxing problems ?

Comment: Look into this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader. Voting for close since this is a request for code.

Comment: When you take a tour on the "Welcome to Stack Overflow" site and you scroll down to the 2nd paragraph "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" you can read there :    Ask about ... √ specific programming problems, √ Software algorithms, √ Coding techniques, √ Software developments tools.   Did I missunderstand something with this forum ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions (that I have slightly reworded for clarity):

1. > How to retrieve the movie's local url from the file-input ?

   Say, for example, the user populates the file-input with:
   `c:\Users\Username\My Documents\file.ext`
   On modern browsers (except IE with a relaxed security-setting which is pretty much only intended for trusted private intranet-use) **you can *not* get the actual local *path*** (`c:\Users\Username\My Documents\`) as that would present an obvious privacy-issue (a security-problem).
   Instead you'll get `C:\fakepath\`.
   Getting the filename and extension (`file.ext`) is no problem.
   Please see my [detailed up-to-date answer about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079).
2. > How to pass the file's URL to the video's src attribute ?

   To solve the problem of not having a valid URL (in this case using the `file:///` protocol) to set to the video's source-attribute (or image, audio, etc..), modern browsers have the [`URL Store`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_object_URLs).

   One can think of this as being a small local private (other's can't access it) mini-webserver (including status-codes for XMLHttpRequest) serving any kind of binary or data.
   These URL's can never live longer than a browser's session (so storing them in local storage etc, is useless) OR one can revoke automatically on first use (using `createFor`) or manually using (`revokeObjectURL`).

   In this case a simple `URL.createObjectURL(/*file-reference*/)` will create the anonymous URL for the actual local file-path in the browser's URL Store that you can then use like any other served content.

   See the following example, *just* to get you started:

   ```js
   window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;  //fallback for older prefixed objects

   document.getElementById('loadMedia').onclick=function(){
     document.getElementById('fileToOpen').click();
   };

   document.getElementById('fileToOpen').onchange=function(){
     if(this.files && this.files[0]){
       var vid = document.getElementById('vid');
       document.getElementById('vid_name').innerHTML=this.files[0].name;
       // revoke previous url
       vid.getAttribute('src') && URL.revokeObjectURL(vid.getAttribute('src'));
           // set new url
       vid.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
       vid.load();
     }
   };
   ```

   ```html
   <label for="fileToOpen">
     <button type="file"  id="loadMedia" class="loadMediabutton button">Load Movie</button>
   </label>
   <input type="File" name="loadMedia" id="fileToOpen" style="display:none">
   <span id="vid_name"></span>
   <br>
   <video id="vid" controls="controls"></video>
   ```

   <sup>Note, with flashblocker installed there is no video-element until the user has activated it, just like with flash.. Both getting the video-element and subsequently setting it's source is not possible until the user 'runs' the blocked video-element. Solving this was outside my scope for this answer.</sup>
3. > How to avoid sandboxing problems ?

   What problems, to my knowledge you are not dealing with the sandboxed filesystem here (since you are not copying the local file to the local sandboxed file-system for storage)?
   Local files (or in-memory BLOB's) that the URL Store links to are read-only!
   The user manually 'shared' the file(s) (by selecting/populating a file-input on a web-page/app). From that point on, the application could read/upload/analyze/what-ever to the file (but not change/delete/overwrite/etc it).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I am very new to this web security issues. So it'll take some time to go through the steps. I come back and will report how I succed or failed :-(  Thanks