# jQuery file upload with paperclip, showing preview image before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-file-upload

**I'm trying to accomplish like [this](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)**

[image]

Trying to show preview of the images that I want to upload, but nothing is showing up. I'm looking at my log and when I try to upload, the log is spitting out stuff, mostly `Image Exists (0.2ms)` and `Image Load (0.3ms)`, and showing `SELECT 1 AS....` SQL syntax

## This is my form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @photo, html: { multipart: true, id: 'bePhoto' } do |f| %>    
  <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
            <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            <span>Cancel upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <!-- The global file processing state -->
        <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
    </div>

    <!-- The global progress state -->
    <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
        <!-- The global progress bar -->
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- The extended global progress state -->
        <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->

<table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>

<% end %>
```

## Then I have this javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#bePhoto').fileupload();

    $('#bePhoto').addClass('fileupload-processing');
      $.ajax({
          // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
          //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
          url: $('#bePhoto').fileupload('option', 'url'),
          dataType: 'json',
          context: $('#beTripForm')[0]
      }).always(function () {
          $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
      }).done(function (result) {
          $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
              .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });    
});
```

## I also have this

```
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
```

## And this:

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic-plus
```

I pretty much tried to mimic the sample demo, but not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: What is your Probloem @hellomello?Server side or just showing preview image before upload.

Comment: http://5minutenpause.com/blog/2013/09/04/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-rails-4-and-paperclip/ This may be helpful for you

Comment: @bipashant server side, I'm not able to see previews

Comment: And its uploading automatically, I think its not supposed to upload unless I press the upload button too

Comment: Talking about your requirements You only need to preview the selected files right ?

Comment: Yeah, because right now its already uploading to the database, so I believe I got that covered. Although, I do wish to only upload it when I submit my form..

Comment: Do you have multiple image?

Comment: @bipashant yes, I have multiple images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is to display the selected image before uploading and upload them during form submit I tried to write custom script for this.Please have a look and let me know.

Here I read the input file content and display them in image tag as thumbnail.It doesn't show the progress of file uploading but all the files are submitted during form submit event.

Please add a div to display the thumnail image just above the file input field

```
    <div class="row" id="uploader-wrapper"></div>

    <%= f.file_field(:photo, id: 'photo_upload_btn', multiple: true) %>
```

And add event listner for your file input field.

```
$("#photo_upload_btn").change(function () {
        displayThumbnail(this);
});
```

Add the following Javasript code to display the Thumbnail

```
function displayThumbnail(input) {
        for( var i = 0;i<input.files.length;i++){
            if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    if ($('#photo_upload_btn').valid()) {
                        var $newImageThumbnail = makeElement('img',{ class: "image-frame",src: e.target.result});
                        $('#uploader-wrapper').append($newImageThumbnail);
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    function makeElement(element, options) {
        var $elem = document.createElement(element);
        $.each(options, function (key, value) {
            $elem.setAttribute(key, value);
        });
        return $elem;
    }
```

Also don't forget to style the thumbnail

```
.image-frame {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this late response... I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function`... and then its pointing me to this: `if ($('#photo_upload_btn').valid()) {` line

Comment: Oh my, I had to add a validation jquery script at the end of my app for it to work!! It works! Thank you so much, I guess I have to figure out how to add progress bars now... Hmmm thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supposed to happen, but when I select an image, and then click on the file field to select more images, only the last images that were selected was uploaded only.. (ie, if I select 1 image, and then click on file field again, to select 2 more images, only the last 2 images were uploaded.)

Comment: Yaa
We can't maintain the previous files using this method
please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537696/remember-and-repopulate-file-input