# Remeber file selection

Tags: javascript, forms, file, cakephp, file-upload

I have a form which asks to select a file for upload. PArt of the form requires the user to click through to another page. This is fine as I can store field values in local storage. The problem is the file selection - is there a way to remember what the user selected once they navigate back to the form?

If not can anyone suggest how to implement what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember and Repopulate File Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537696/remember-and-repopulate-file-input)

Answer (score 0):

So as you are not posting some code examples, I assume that your are not interested in code suggestions.

You could use a session to store some data the user gave you over a form. CakePHP comes with the nice session helper, which makes it easy to deal with.

How to use sessions with CakePHP you can find here:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

So everytime the user fills out the form you could store the relevant data inside the session. Inside your view you just check if there is a value for that data in your session. If yes render the session value as default if not you can render the default value.