# How to edit input type=file value?

Tags: html, file, input, types, upload

How to edit input type="file" value="" area... I want to upload my custom file.

My Sample:

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="xmlupload"  method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >

<input type="file" name="xmlupload" value="myCustom.xml" /> 

<input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="send" onclick="form1.submit();">
</form>
```

How to edit type=file value="" (javascript or html) ?

Comment: value is not a permitted attribute for that https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html

Comment: Since your NAA said: '*How to edit file value area? "value" does not work on browser*' this is a duplicate of [Remember and Repopulate File Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537696/remember-and-repopulate-file-input)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using .attr() jQuery or setAttribute() javascript

Example 1 - jQuery

```
$('input[name=xmlupload]').attr("type", "SPECIFY TYPE HERE");
```

Example 2  - Javascript

```
var yourinput = document.getElementsByName("xmlupload").setAttribute("type", "SPECIFY TYPE HERE")
```

These methods should work to set any attribute.

Comment: Thank you, but
How to edit file value area? "value" does not work on browser :( <input type="file" name="xmlupload" value="myCustom.xml" />