# PrimeFaces FileUpload set default path to Import file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-commons-fileupload

We’re using PrimeFaces (mode="advanced") File upload component to perform server side file uploads.

Is there any way to set default path (import file path ) on choose button ? Like C:\Files\ 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember and Repopulate File Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537696/remember-and-repopulate-file-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't.

In long format:
From my understanding, your question is related to the to `<input type="file" />` topic and the browser only can remembered the last path you used for uploading something, which is our situation (photo uploading) is more than sufficient.

Plus, when I faced your issue, I reached [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696884/4906586) which I wholeheartedly agree. As an user, you usually want to avoid having a website knowing your folder hierarchy.

If you wish to read more about this, there is a [wonderful answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/4906586)